# I have 2 codes with Assignment operator and copy constructor and same driver code. But both are giving different output

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

I have 2 codes with Assignment operator and copy constructor and same driver code. But both are giving different output.

Code 1:

```
//constructor, copy constructor, assignment operator and destructor
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A
{
    int a;
    int *b;
public:
    //constructor
    A()
    {
        a=0;
        b = new int;

    }
    
    //Copy constructor
    A (const A& oldObj)
    {
        cout<<"copy ctor"<<endl;
        a = oldObj.a;
        b = new int;
        *b = *(oldObj.b);
    }
    
    //destructor
    ~A()
    {
        delete b;
    }
    
    //Assignment operator overloading
    void operator = (const A& obj)
    {
        cout<<"ass op"<<endl;
        a = obj.a;
        *b = *(obj.b);
    }
    
};


int main()
{
    A a1;
    A a2 = a1; //copy constructor
    
    A a3;
    a3 = a1;//assignment operator
}
```

Code 1 : output

```
copy ctor
ass op
```

Code 2

```
// Simple C++ program to demonstrate use of copy-and-swap
// idiom by improving above code.
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

class anyArrayClass
{
    int size;
    int *ptr;
public:
    anyArrayClass(int s=0):size(s),ptr(size? new int[size]:nullptr) 
    {
        //cout<<"default ctor"<<endl;
        }

    // Copy constructor
    anyArrayClass(const anyArrayClass& obj):size(obj.size),
                        ptr(size? new int[size]:nullptr)
    {
        cout<<"copy ctor"<<endl;
        memmove(ptr, obj.ptr, size*sizeof(int));
    }

    friend void swap(anyArrayClass& obj1, anyArrayClass& obj2)
    {
        cout<<"swap"<<endl;
        std::swap(obj1.size, obj2.size);
        std::swap(obj1.ptr, obj2.ptr);
    }
    
    // overloaded assignment operator
    // argument passed by value. calls copy ctor
    anyArrayClass& operator=(anyArrayClass obj) 
    {
        cout<<"assignment"<<endl;
        // calling friend function
        swap(*this, obj);
        return *this;
    }

    ~anyArrayClass()
    {
        delete[] ptr;
    }
};

int main()
{
    anyArrayClass obj1;
    anyArrayClass obj2 = obj1;//copy
    
    anyArrayClass obj3;
    obj3 =obj1;//assignment
}
```

Code 2 output:

```
copy ctor
copy ctor
assignment
swap
```

In code 2, last 3 lines of output is coming from assignment operator call (line no 55).
Why it is calling copy constructor?

Answer (score 1):

In the 1st code, your assignment operator takes an `A` object *by (const) reference*, so a new `A` object does not need to be created during each assignment.

In the 2nd code, your assignment operator takes an `anyArrayClass` object *by value*, so a new `anyArrayClass` object has to be created during every assignment.  And since `anyArrayClass` does not implement a move constructor, the copy constructor is used.